# Insert Into HANA Table Specifying Columns

Tags: sql, teradata, hana

I'm coming from a Teradata environment where

```
create table mytable  
(  
first_column varchar(50),  
second_column varchar(50),  
third_column varchar(50)  
)  

insert into mytable values (first_column = 'one', second_column = 'first')  
insert into mytable values (first_column = 'two', third_column = 'second')
```

is possible.  This does not seem to be possible in HANA even with **default** specified

```
create column table mytable 
(  
"FIRST_COLUMN" varchar(50) default null,  
"SECOND_COLUMN" varchar(50) default null,  
"THIRD_COLUMN" varchar(50) default null  
)
```

I could create a row with a unique ID specifying NULLs for all the fields and then UPDATE the columns I want using the ID which seems time consuming and awkward or is there a better way?

Comment: Wow, I've never seen such syntax, I didn't even know this is possible (besides Macro parameters). Must be a leftover of the pre-SQL syntax :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the standard syntax:

```
insert into mytable (first_column, second_column)
    values ('one', 'first');
```

This should work both in Hana and Teradata -- and any other database.